# Is there a way to use 'pool_reset_connection' from mysql-connector-python with MariaDB 10.4.7?

Tags: python-3.x, mariadb, mysql-connector-python

I want to change my python program from a normal connection to a Connection Pool so that the database connection doesn't get lost when no queries are sent for some hours, as well as the database not being overwhelmed with a bunch of queries at once at peak usage.

I'm using Python 3.7.4, mysql-connector-python 8.0.17, and MariaDB 10.4.7.
It works fine when I use a normal connection, but MariaDB apparently doesn't support the `pool_reset_session` setting of `mysql.connector.pooling.MySQLConnectionPool`

At the start of my code, it tries to create the database if it doesn't yet exist, and that is causing the errors I get.

```
import mysql.connector as mariadb
from mysql.connector import errorcode
from mysql.connector import pooling

cnx = mariadb.pooling.MySQLConnectionPool(user='root', password='password', host='localhost', 
                                          pool_name='connectionpool', pool_size=10, pool_reset_session=True)

try:
    db = cnx.get_connection()
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS tests")
    print("Created database")
except mariadb.Error as err:
    print(f"Failed creating database: {err}")
finally:
    print("Finally (create)")
    db.close()
```

I expected that this snippet would just create the database `tests` but instead I got the following two errors:

`mysql.connector.errors.NotSupportedError: MySQL version 5.7.2 and earlier does not support COM_RESET_CONNECTION.`

as well as

`mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: 1047 (08S01): Unknown command`

From the traceback logs, it looks like this gets caused by trying to execute `db.close()` in line 17.

Full output with traceback:
https://pastebin.com/H3SAvA9N

I am asking what I can do to fix this and if it's possible at all to use this sort of connection pooling with MariaDB 10.4.7 (I get confused because it says that MySQL <= 5.7.2 doesn't support this reset of connections after use even though I use MariaDB 10.4.7)

I also found out that MariaDB Connector/J does provide such an option, called `useResetConnection` but I don't want to learn Java just for this feature.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was facing the same issue with mysql-connector-python for mariaDB, and I downgraded mysql-connector-python version to 8.0.12 and it worked for me

Comment: The only working solution in this thread. Downgraded version to 8.0.12 and problem gone.

Comment: I was also getting `1047 (08S01): Unknown command` when I tried to close connection from a connection pool. I was on version 8.0.19. I tried all versions between 8.0.12 to 8.0.19 and it started to break at 8.0.17 (i.e., Unknown command error), so I settled on 8.0.16.

Answer (score 7):

As @Georg Richter indicate, MariaDB for historical reason return a version like
"5.5.5-10.4.10-MariaDB-1:10.4.10+maria~bionic-log"

MySQL python connector check explicitly version (https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-python/blob/b034f25ec8037f5d60015bf2ed4ee278ec12fd17/lib/mysql/connector/connection.py#L1157) and since MariaDB server appears as version 5.5.5, an error is thrown.

Since MariaDB 10.2.6, you can explicitly add `version` to the [server] section of the cnf file.

With configuration like:

```
[server]
. . . 
version=5.7.99-10.4.10-MariaDB
```

Connector will see version 5.7.99, and behave accordingly.

Comment: Works like charm. I use MariaDB 10.3.22 as slave and MySQL 5.7.29 as master. This configuration works after I add version to cnf file in MariaDB server. Thanks a lot.

Comment: works. just edited /etc/my.csv and added the above line, and restarted the service.

Comment: @vikaskv, do you mean /etc/my.cnf?  I can't get this solution to work no matter which file I try.

Answer (score 2):

When bumping the server version to 10.0, MariaDB had to add a prefix to the server version to avoid breaking replication (replication protocol expects a one digit major version number, for more information check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56601304/what-does-the-first-part-of-the-mariadb-version-string-mean/56607492#56607492)).

No matter if you use MariaDB 10.0 or 10.4, MySQL Connector/Python will always return version number 5.5.5:

```
>>> conn= mysql.connector.connect(user="foo")
>>> print(conn.get_server_version())
(5, 5, 5)
>>> cursor=conn.cursor()
>>> cursor.execute("select version()")
>>> row=cursor.fetchone()
>>> print(row)
('10.4.7-MariaDB-log',)
```

`COM_RESET_CONNECTION` which resets the connection on server side was introduced in MariaDB 10.2, so to make it work you have to change the code of MySQL Connector/Python, e.g. in _check_server_version (abstracts.py):

```
+        if server_version.startswith("5.5.5-")
+            server_version= server_version[6:]
```

This is of course not a generic solution, since it will not work for MariaDB versions prior 10.2. It might have also bad side effects when checking for certain features like X-Protocol, which isn't supported by MariaDB.

Comment: Would I experience those bad side effects if all I do is just query the MariaDB server for standard SQL queries? Like `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, `CREATE`, etc?

Comment: For "normal' statements and for using the main api calls (as documented in PEP-249) there shouldn't be bad side affects. Fyi: MariaDB is also working on a new MariaDB Connector for Python, the first GA will be available within next months.

Comment: Really? I had no idea. I'll try out your answer's solution above and see if it works out for my purposes.
And I will be very eagerly looking forward to that MariaDB/Python Connector after having seen that Java already has its own

Comment: Of course, if you have buggy logic, like not freeing unread resultsets (not closing a cursor after using unbuffered resultsets) the connection will not be reusable. Btw What version of C/Python do you use?

Comment: If you mean my Python version, I am using the 3.7.4 x64 version on Windows (I'm still pretty new to Python and all that stuff, so I apologize if I misunderstood your question)
And I already learned that lesson about the unused results the hard way some time ago :-D

Comment: Hi @GeorgRichter I'm having the same problem using python 3.8.2 and mysql-connector-python==8.0.19 but I'm not getting any good improvement; I try as u say to check the server_version and change it but I always get other library issue when I try to change the mysql-connector library.... any help or advice of how to solve it? I create a new post too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61173405/why-mysql-connector-works-without-problem-with-python2-7-and-not-with-python3